# TI-nspire CX CAS giving weird/incorrect indefinite integral

Tags: integration, calculator

I am testing out the new TI-nspire CX CAS I just got with some simple indefinite integrals. I used the integral of

$$ \int \sec^3(x) dx $$

My nspire gives me:

$$ \frac{\cos^2(x)\ln\left(-\frac{|\cos(x)|}{\sin (x)}\right)+\sin (x)}{2\cos^2(x)} $$

Symbolab gives a much simpler answer that does not equate to the above one:

$$ \frac{\sec^2(x)\sin(x)}{2} + \frac12\ln\big|\tan(x)+\sec(x)\big| $$

Is there a way to change the formatting of the nspire?

Comment: No, because every CAS is different. You have to identites to show the two are equal.

Comment: Your post will be better received if you follow the site's formatting. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)